# How to sort by date in SOLR?

Tags: search, solr

I want to sort the results and scores returning from SOLR search,how I can get scores based on date like below:

```
Suppose for keywords "football"
  12-10-2012 - 3.2
  13-10-2012 - 1.5
```

My solr date filed lis like below:

```
  <field name="published_date" datetimeformat="dd-MM-yyyy"  type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I checked this [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters) but couldn't find that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can pass the [sort](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter) parameter in the URL

e.g. `sort=published_date desc` for documents by published date in descending order.

If you want to sort by score and date you can use `sort=score desc, published_date desc`

Comment: when m querying the solr server the space between date and desc in sort=published_date desc is getting replaced %20

Answer (score 1):

taken from [the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax)

```
Although not technically a Syntax difference, please note that if you use 
the Solr "DateField" type, any queries on those fields (typically range queries) 
should use either the Complete ISO 8601 Date syntax that field supports, 
or the DateMath Syntax to get
relative dates. Examples:

timestamp:[* TO NOW]

createdate:[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO *]

createdate:[1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z TO 2007-03-06T00:00:00Z]

pubdate:[NOW-1YEAR/DAY TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]

createdate:[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO 1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z+1YEAR]

createdate:[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z/YEAR TO 1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z] 

NOTE:TO must be uppercase, or Solr will report a 'Range Goop' error.
```

combine that with [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29) and the job is done :) it's pretty easy, it just requires some tries in the beginning

a little edit: this method allows you to retrieve values based on a date range and apply a score boost to them according to their values. apparently you were asking help on how to retrieve sort on base score and date, so my answer isn't the 100% correct one

Comment: wiki https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/QueryParser - recent Solr differentiates between `lucerne` and other parsers https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/standard-query-parser.html - see generic docs  https://solr.apache.org/guide/ - the wiki is currently being rebuilt https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr

Comment: More recent date formatting docs: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/date-formatting-math.html