# How should I sort by date results?: Solr

Tags: sorting, solr

I'm trying to sort results by date. The server is using Solr technology. Earlier, I was using:

```
urldata.sort = 'last_modified desc';
```

to sort by date results. Now it seems to be not working. It throws error:

[image]

I referred to this answer regarding sort by date in Solr: [How to sort by date in SOLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970666/how-to-sort-by-date-in-solr)

I tried to change 'last_modified desc' to 'published_date desc' but it seems to be not working. How should I proceed to solve this error?

Comment: just try urldata.sort = last_modified desc; (not in a string format)

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't related to sorting, but that you aren't search a specific field for any particular value. Since there is no default field defined or specified in the URL, Solr has no idea what do with your search.

Try setting `df` in the URL, query a specific field `foo:value` or use `qf` (with (e)dismax) to specify which field Solr should sort.

Ordering, as long as the field is specified as a date field, should work automagically.